# React Native background notifications with firebase and php

Tags: php, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I am new to react native and have created an app that displays a list of events which are stored in a mysql database and converted to json with php. The list of events is then displayed in a react native flatlist.

I could like a background notification each time an event is added to the flatlist. After doing some research I found the best way to send background notifications is to use firebase. I was able to set up background notification and send then from the firebase console.

Here is my code.

```js
const getFcmToken = async () => {
  const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
  if (fcmToken) {
      console.log("Your Firebase Token is:", fcmToken);
  } else {
      console.log("Failed", "No Token Recived");
  }
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  requestUserPermission = async () => {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;
      if (enabled) {
        getFcmToken();
        console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
      }
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
      await this.requestUserPermission();
      fetch('http://ad9e61f2797a.ngrok.io/Notifications.php');
      
       // Register background handler
       messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
       console.log('Messaage handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
  });

      // When app is in the background and clicked
      messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(async (remoteMessage) => {
        console.log('Notification caused app to open from background state:', remoteMessage.notification);
      });

      // when app is in closed and clicked
      messaging()
        .getInitialNotification()
        .then(remoteMessage => {
          if (remoteMessage) {
            console.log('Notifivation caused app to open from closed state:', remoteMessage.notification);
        }    
    });
};
)
```

I would like my notifications do send without having to use the firebase cconsole. I have created php server code to try and do this but I can't seem to get the notifications to show up.

Here is my php code

```js
<?php
$url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
$token = "xxxxxxxx";
$serverKey = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$title = "Title";
$body = "Body of the message";
$notification = array('title' => $title, 'text' => $body, 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => '1');
$arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification, 'priority' => 'high');
$json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: key=' . $serverKey;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
// Send the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);
// Close request
if ($response === FALSE) {
    die('FCM Send Error: ' , curl_errno($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

I am trying to run my app on my iPhone.